# How to best use %>% operator in an R package?

Tags: r, package

Pipes and dplyr are useful for quick data exploration. Some argue that in a package, their use is not ideal.

In a package, I have to first add a package to the dependency.
Like this `devtools::use_package("dplyr")`

And than I have to prefix it with dplyr:: when I use any function.
How do I do that for the pipe operator?  do I say: `magrittr::%>%`?

I would ideally use in a package a code like this:

```
data %<>% group_by(a,b,c) %>% summarize(total=sum(d)) %>% ungroup()
```

Do I have to always say

```
data magrittr::%<>% dplyr::group_by(a,b,c) magrittr::%>% dplyr::summarize(total=sum(d)) %>% ungroup()
```

What is the best practice for pipes and dplyr in an R package?

Answer (score 7):

Rather than repeated `magrittr::%>%` calls, I would suggest importing the pipe as part of your package.  This way you can use the pipe within your own code, without the repeated `::`.

In use this:

```
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
magrittr::`%>%`
```